# very slow query with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I have read through many tutorials online and here on stackoverflow but I still can't figure out how to solve the problem I'm facing right now.

I would like to tell you guys that I'm a mysql newbie so please forgive my noobness.

Alright, the query is this and it grabs the information that I need from wordpress database

```
SELECT 
  product.ID productId, 
  product.guid productLink,
  product.post_title productTitle,
  post.ID postId,
  post.post_title postTitle,
  post.post_content postContent,
  post.post_date postDate,
  tm.slug typeSlug, tm.name typeName,
  tm2.slug langSlug, tm2.name langName,
  tm3.slug pubSlug, tm3.name pubName,
IFNULL(wl.id,0) wishlist
FROM wp_posts product
    JOIN wp_postmeta meta ON meta.meta_key = 'p2m' AND meta.meta_value=product.ID
    JOIN wp_posts post ON post.ID = meta.post_id

JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = product.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id  = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'mtype'
JOIN wp_terms tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id

JOIN wp_term_relationships tr2 ON tr2.object_id = product.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2 ON tt2.term_taxonomy_id  = tr2.term_taxonomy_id AND tt2.taxonomy = 'language'
JOIN wp_terms tm2 ON tm2.term_id = tt2.term_id

JOIN wp_term_relationships tr3 ON tr3.object_id = product.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt3 ON tt3.term_taxonomy_id  = tr3.term_taxonomy_id AND tt3.taxonomy = 'publisher'
JOIN wp_terms tm3 ON tm3.term_id = tt3.term_id

LEFT JOIN wp_yith_wcwl wl ON wl.user_id = 1 AND wl.prod_id = product.ID AND wl.post_id = post.ID


WHERE product.post_type = 'product'

ORDER BY post.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,35
```

---

When I remove "ORDER BY post.post_date DESC" the speed of the query gets down to .03 seconds which is freaking amazing.. But with the addition of the "ORDER BY post.post_date DESC" the speed of the query goes to amazing 10+ seconds which is way too long..

I've used EXPLAIN and it seems that there is usage of filesort when the ORDER BY by date gets into the query.

I need to have my query reply back the results according to the post_date so I can't figure out what I could do at this point...

Additionally, I would like to point it out that in [Database Description of wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts) there is an INDEX referred as "type_status_date" which could be used in my case. However, I'm totally clueless where to use it and how to do it. If there is anyone who can point out the flaw in the logic of my query or help me out with the optimization of the query (or index) please do so. Thanks for you kind attention!

P.S: I don't know how to create an index too :)

[Initial Result of EXPLAIN with ORDER BY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhvxw.png)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what happens if you do `SELECT * FROM (my query without order by and limit) x ORDER BY ... LIMIT`. Incidentally, there is another way of writing this query, but it's generally slightly slower than your method, so I'll keep it under my hat for now.

Comment: @Strawberry - is the other way to pull the most recent 35 posts by ID, and then drive from there?

Comment: I've tried it and pulling the results by ID doesn't get the right results on all times

Comment: It won't, the first 35 do not necessarily satisfy the joins and other predicates.

Comment: Actually, the posts are made so that they satisfy all the requirements but IDs of the posts aren't in correlation with the dates of the posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JOIN wp_postmeta meta
       ON meta.meta_key = 'p2m'       -- filters
      AND meta.meta_value=product.ID  -- shows relation
```

is confusing.  `JOIN...ON` is used to say how two tables are related.  Filters belong in `WHERE`:

```
    WHERE ...
      AND meta.meta_key = 'p2m'
      ...
```

wp_postmeta is not well indexed.  More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) .

Adding `INDEX(post_date)` may or may not help performance -- It depends on how quickly 35 good rows are found.

From the `EXPLAIN`, we see that the worst part is getting into `meta` -- something like 30K rows to look through.  This _estimates that there are 30 rows with `meta_key = 'p2m'`.  How many rows are there?

Unfortunately `wp_postmeta` is not designed to efficiently start with the meta_key+meta_value.  This is a general problem with key-value stores (such as Posts in WP), especially when the 'value' is `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: Hello Rick. There are 30k rows and increasing on daily basis right now.. I assume it will reach 100k by the end of this month and maybe more.. So quite perplexed at the moment to solve out the problem.. I will try WHERE instead of Join On within an hour or so

Comment: Rick James it seems you were right.. At least in my case.. wp_postmeta table is way too inefficient for so many joins to be working at the same time. I deleted 6 rows of joins and the results were able to be worked out within 1 sec.

Comment: By the way, you have written that its possible to change JOIN ON to WHERE AND.. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Move `meta.meta_key = 'p2m'` out of the `ON` into the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rick. I agree with your post about the inadequacy of wp_postmeta database of wordpress after almost month of in depth working with wordpress database system. I didn't try the method you have written in rjweb.org but I believe that the wordpress core developers should take a look at it. At the moment, this aspect (wp_postmeta) or the whole structure of the wordpress database isn't sufficient to run high traffic, big data websites unless you use high-end hardware. I believe the database itself could be optimized at the core to make such websites run on lower-end hardware.

Comment: @Ali - I agree.  WP should improve the schema from the core out.  I don't have the energy to get directly involved.

Answer (score 0):

The index on wp_post for type_status_date, has the date field as the third field of the index,

```
type_status_date INDEX 
post_type
post_status
post_date
ID
```

So you have a predicate for post type, but post status is not included in your query in any predicate, at best it can therefore do a partial index scan of the index (sometimes called a skip scan or range scan depending on the db, my sql is not going to play ball easily on that) but it will be slower.

That is a best case scenario though, with all those joins and additional fields not covered by the index the cost of the index scan and row lookups could be far too high to consider even touching the index vs a straight scan.

It would help if you post the explain plan, it would help confirm what the optimizer was doing. The above is a more generic DB engine commentary.

Comment: I added the picture file where the result of the EXPLAIN could be seen. Thanks for your time and kind attention

Answer (score 0):

type_status_date is a combined index so it's used only if you order by all it's components. It cannot be used by MySQL to order by only post_date. So the best solution is to add an index by post_date.